# How can I close a browser/page using jQuery if the page was not opned using window.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, window

I have a logout event in my site and once the user clicks on logout they cookies are cleared and I also display a link to close the page or the browser if the user wants.

The link id to close the browser is `closeBrowser`

Here is my `jQuery` code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#closeBrowser').click(function(){        
        window.close();
    });
});
```

I think it is not working because the page was not opened with `window.open() event`. However, I am not sure.

How can I close the page once the user clicks on that link??

Thanks

Comment: That "should" work just fine. As `window` implies current window already. Can you jsfiddle more of the code maybe? Maybe there is an error in your selector? At this moment, hard to tell as that code appears fine.

Comment: On a side note, if you're running jQuery 1.3+ (i think), you can easily drop that old, long ` $(document).ready(function(){` && replace it with `$(function() {`

Comment: You can only close windows that you actually opened yourself. You can't close windows that does'nt belong to you for obvious security reasons.

Comment: you should have got something on console ?

Comment: @adeno not true. open your console right now and type `window.close()` then run. hehehe

Comment: @SpYk3HH - that only works in the console, not on an actual page.

Comment: @SpYk3HH if u have tried some more examples (pages which are not opened with window.open() i.e. open google; search anything; then type window.close() in console) u did not use "hehehe".. :P

Answer (score 0):

The **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close)** for `window.close()` states :

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened
>   by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:
>   Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: That's true in FF, but in IE, you can use `window.opener = self; window.close();` meaning there has to be alternate method around this. Or once again, IE just doesn't care about security. lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH - as far as I know, no other browser will let you close windows with javascript unless you specifically opened those windows with javascript.